# Highlighting better the current editor group

Tags: visual-studio-code

Does VSCode provide a way of highlighting the current **editor group** (or tab) **in focus**?

For example:

- Highlighting **a bounding box** around the group in focus with a separate color (illustration below)
- Highlighting the **current tab** in the group in focus

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For modifying the active tab see https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color#editor-groups-tabs.  For example:

`tab.activeBackground`, `tab.activeForeground` and there a few more `active/inactive` color settings to modify in that link.  They go in your settings `colorCustomizations` object like:

```
"workbench.colorCustomizations": {

  "tab.activeBackground": "#ff0"
}
```

In general, https://code.visualstudio.com/api/references/theme-color is the resource for looking up what items can be modified in this way.

---

It doesn't look there is a way to differentiate an active from an inactive editorGroup except for a focused but empty editorGroup, with `editorGroup.focusedEmptyBorder`.  You might find some other editorGroup colors useful though.

---

You might also be interested in https://stackoverflow.com/a/76980603/836330 which shows how to dim editors and terminals that are unfocused.  It doesn't explicitly work on editor groups but the effect is similar - make a focused editor more obvious (by reducing the opacity of other editors and the terminal).

Answer (score 3):

By using `tab.unfocusedActiveBackground` you can highlight inderectly the current active editor group:

```
  "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
    "tab.activeBackground": "#770000",
    "tab.unfocusedActiveBackground": "#000033"
  }
```

It is the best I have found yet.

[View here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BRfKs.png)

Answer (score 3):

I also want a solution to this issue... I do have a solution which might be "good enough", at least for now. You need to use an extension such as [Custom CSS and JS Loader](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=be5invis.vscode-custom-css) to load your own CSS. I was able to construct these styles which highlight the active editor group.

```css
.editor-group-container.active:before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

With this basis, you can modify the CSS to highlight other containers in the editor such as the side bar, or the activity bar when they contain an element in focus.

```css
:is(
    .editor-group-container,
    #workbench\.parts\.sidebar,
    #workbench\.parts\.activitybar,
):has(:focus):before {
    content: "";
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 10;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
    pointer-events: none;
}
```

You may want to adjust this CSS. At the moment the activity bar doesn't work, as there is already a `:before` element.

[image: Screenshot of CSS in action.]

Comment: Hi! I tried this but could not manage to get it to work. 

Do I just copy put the css you have in the second codeblock and put in a css file?
There is nothing else I need to add to the css?

(which I then reference as per the extensions instructions)

Screenshot of what I got: 
https://imgur.com/a/5LDsC9g